# Power issue with the kernel, and the Kernel Security Check Failure BSODs

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have been getting 'Kernel Security Check Failure' BSODs sometimes when I start the vpn client or rarely when I start Kaspersky 17, but never ever when I play demanding games and never while browsing.  And today in Windows Events I found the error is kernel power.  Yes, I changed the PSU (to CORSAIR CS850M), but do the symptoms say so? Nvidia driver updated, temps are fine too.

Crash Dump Analysis:

```
Crash dump directory: C:\Windows\Minidump

Crash dumps are enabled on your computer.

On Fri 05-05-2017 06:11:40 PM your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\050517-18734-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x14A510) 
Bugcheck code: 0x139 (0x3, 0xFFFF8001B2C60C40, 0xFFFF8001B2C60B98, 0x0)
Error: KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: The kernel has detected the corruption of a critical data structure.
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time. 



On Fri 05-05-2017 06:11:40 PM your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\memory.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: klim6.sys (klim6+0x2C72) 
Bugcheck code: 0x139 (0x3, 0xFFFF8001B2C60C40, 0xFFFF8001B2C60B98, 0x0)
Error: KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
file path: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\klim6.sys
product: System Interceptors PDK
company: AO Kaspersky Lab
description: Packet Network Filter [fre_win8_x64]
Bug check description: The kernel has detected the corruption of a critical data structure.
A third party driver was identified as the probable root cause of this system error. It is suggested you look for an update for the following driver: klim6.sys (Packet Network Filter [fre_win8_x64], AO Kaspersky Lab). 
Google query: AO Kaspersky Lab KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE



On Tue 25-04-2017 07:16:37 PM your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\042517-20718-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x14A510) 
Bugcheck code: 0x139 (0x3, 0xFFFFF803B5680C60, 0xFFFFF803B5680BB8, 0x0)
Error: KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: The kernel has detected the corruption of a critical data structure.
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time. 



On Sun 09-04-2017 09:38:25 PM your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\040917-19890-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x14A510) 
Bugcheck code: 0x139 (0x3, 0xFFFFB201D3745BB0, 0xFFFFB201D3745B08, 0x0)
Error: KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: The kernel has detected the corruption of a critical data structure.
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time. 



On Sun 09-04-2017 12:43:02 PM your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\040917-20453-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x14A510) 
Bugcheck code: 0x139 (0x3, 0xFFFFD501E42B5370, 0xFFFFD501E42B52C8, 0x0)
Error: KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: The kernel has detected the corruption of a critical data structure.
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time. 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Conclusion
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

12 crash dumps have been found and analyzed. Only 5 are included in this report. A third party driver has been identified to be causing system crashes on your computer. It is strongly suggested that you check for updates for these drivers on their company websites. Click on the links below to search with Google for updates for these drivers: 

klim6.sys (Packet Network Filter [fre_win8_x64], AO Kaspersky Lab)

If no updates for these drivers are available, try searching with Google on the names of these drivers in combination with the errors that have been reported for these drivers. Include the brand and model name of your computer as well in the query. This often yields interesting results from discussions on the web by users who have been experiencing similar problems.
```

[Here's a screenshot of the dump files.](https://snag.gy/dxLhK7.jpg)

Comment: Have you used windbg to diagnose the problem?

Comment: what version of windows 10? i would upgrade to the latest. also would try the following: 1.) upgrade BIOS  2.) run command: chkdsk /f C:

Comment: Latest windows,BIOS latest.If by any chance hardware issue?or symptoms completely say software...?

Comment: Are the BSODs Hardware related?
https://ufile.io/m9ger
https://ufile.io/g4fwr
https://ufile.io/jyg0l
https://ufile.io/lrlfu
https://ufile.io/e1aak
https://ufile.io/stqz8
https://ufile.io/92znw
https://ufile.io/r6rwr
https://ufile.io/lgk7p
https://ufile.io/7b8zw
https://ufile.io/cs3ao
https://ufile.io/a7lbs

Comment: any update? have you updated or removed kaspersky?

Answer (score 0):

[Analyzing the dump with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks), shows that you should update your kaspersky Antivirus suite to latest version. Your is from 2016 and `klim6.sys`, `kneps.sys` may cause it:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE (139)
A kernel component has corrupted a critical data structure.  The corruption
could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this machine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A LIST_ENTRY has been corrupted (i.e. double remove).
Arg2: ffffd48003f37bb0, Address of the trap frame for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffd48003f37b08, Address of the exception record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Reserved

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for klim6.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for klim6.sys
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for kneps.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for kneps.sys

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000409

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000003

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  FAIL_FAST_LIST_ENTRY_CORRUPT

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiFastFailDispatch
03 nt!KiRaiseSecurityCheckFailure
04 klim6
05 0x0
06 kneps
07 0x0
09 0x0
0a kneps
0b 0x0
0c kneps
0d 0x0
0f 0x0
10 kneps
11 kneps
12 0x0
13 0x0
14 kneps
15 0x0
18 0x0
19 kneps
1a 0x0
1b kneps
1c 0x0


Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\klim6.sys
Image name: klim6.sys
Browse all global symbols  functions  data
Timestamp:        Tue Aug 23 12:42:09 2016 (57BC2881)
CheckSum:         00011AA6

Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\kneps.sys
Image name: kneps.sys
Browse all global symbols  functions  data
Timestamp:        Mon May 16 15:33:56 2016
```

So go to [Kaspersky page and download](https://www.kaspersky.com/downloads) the latest version.